# Retrieving elements that has a tag - XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

From the sample xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
        <country>
            <name>Liechtenstein</name>
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
            <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
            <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        </country>
        <country>
            <name>Singapore</name>
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        </country>
        <country>
            <name>Panama</name>
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
            <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
        </country>
    </data>
```

Using Python ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')


for elem in tree.iter(tag='name'):
    print (elem.tag)
```

displays three name elements. How can I retrive just one name element `<name>Panama</name>` with a specfic text.

`for elem in tree.iter(tag="name='panama'"):` not working

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using `xpath` in `lxml`. Using `text()` enables you to find 'Panama' as the content of an element quickly. Once you have done that you can navigate to neighbouring information items for the same country.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> tree.xpath('.//name/text()')
['Liechtenstein', 'Singapore', 'Panama']
>>> for item in tree.xpath('.//name/text()'):
...     if item == 'Panama':
...         for cousins in item.getparent().getparent().getchildren():
...             cousins.text
...             
'Panama'
'68'
'2011'
'13600'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
countries = tree.findall("country")
for country in countries:
    name = country.find("name")
    if name.text == "Panama":
        print(name.text)
```

Also, please note that your xml is not well formed. You have an ] instead of an > in line 19 of test.xml